# Make a column that stores the running total of a count for values in another column based on condition in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Week Number    Department    Job        Complete.Status    Overdue.Status
1              A             a1         FALSE                TRUE
1              B             b3         FALSE                TRUE
2              B             b1         TRUE                 TRUE
2              D             d2         TRUE                 FALSE
2              A             a1         TRUE                 TRUE
2              A             a2         FALSE                TRUE
2              C             c1         TRUE                 FALSE
2              B             b1         FALSE                TRUE
2              C             c1         FALSE                FALSE
2              B             b2         TRUE                 TRUE
2              B             b1         TRUE                 FALSE
2              C             c1         FALSE                FALSE
2              B             b2         TRUE                 FALSE
4              B             b1         TRUE                 TRUE
4              A             a1         FALSE                FALSE
4              D             d2         TRUE                 FALSE
```

Note that some jobs may have not been reported for a given week; in the case above there are no reports for week 3.

My objective is to calculate certain metrics for each week. One such metric is the percentage of jobs completed on time.

In this case, I first filtered out all of the incomplete jobs and then applied the following code successfully:

```
df %>%
filter(Complete.Status) %>%
group_by(Week Number, Department, Job) %>% 
summarise(N = n(), n = sum(!Overdue.Status), Percent_Completed_On_Time = n/N)
```

In this case, I would get the following result:

```
Week Number    Department    Job    N    n    Percent_Completed_On_Time
2              A             a1     1    1    1
2              B             b1     2    1    0.5
2              B             b2     2    1    0.5
2              C             c1     1    1    1
4              B             b1     1    0    0
4              D             d2     1    1    1
```

However, another objective I have is to calculate the percentage of jobs completed per week. This is done by dividing the number of complete jobs per week N by (N + cumulative sum of incomplete jobs up to the given week).

In this case, I can't filter out the incomplete jobs. I would like my desired output to be something like:

```
Week Number    Department    Job    N    n    Percent_Completed_On_Time    Percent_Completion
1              A             a1     NA   NA   NA                           0             
1              B             b3     NA   NA   NA                           0
2              A             a1     1    1    1                            0.5
2              A             a2     NA   NA   NA                           0
2              B             b1     2    1    0.5                          0.667
2              B             b2     2    1    0.5                          1
2              C             c1     1    1    1                            0.333
3              NA            NA     NA   NA   NA                           NA
4              B             b1     1    0    0                            0.5
4              D             d2     1    1    1                            1
```

In particular, the jobs a1 and b1 change in the Percent_Completion metric because we are taking only the jobs completed in the current week and dividing it by (jobs completed in current week + jobs not complete up until that week).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
df %>%
  # filter(Complete.Status) %>%
   group_by(Week_Number, Department, Job) %>% 
   summarise(N = n(), n = sum(!Overdue.Status), Percent_Completed_On_Time = n/N,
             Percent_Completion = sum(Complete.Status) / (N + cumsum(Overdue.Status)))
# A tibble: 16 x 7
# Groups:   Week_Number, Department, Job [11]

   Week_Number Department Job       N     n Percent_Completed_On_Time Percent_Completion
         <dbl> <chr>      <chr> <int> <int>                     <dbl>              <dbl>
 1           1 A          a1        1     0                     0                  0    
 2           1 B          b3        1     0                     0                  0    
 3           2 A          a1        1     0                     0                  0.5  
 4           2 A          a2        1     0                     0                  0    
 5           2 B          b1        3     1                     0.333              0.5  
 6           2 B          b1        3     1                     0.333              0.4  
 7           2 B          b1        3     1                     0.333              0.4  
 8           2 B          b2        2     1                     0.5                0.667
 9           2 B          b2        2     1                     0.5                0.667
10           2 C          c1        3     3                     1                  0.333
11           2 C          c1        3     3                     1                  0.333
12           2 C          c1        3     3                     1                  0.333
13           2 D          d2        1     1                     1                  1    
14           4 A          a1        1     1                     1                  0    
15           4 B          b1        1     0                     0                  0.5  
16           4 D          d2        1     1                     1                  1
```

Comment: Yes, I think I could work with this. I didn't know about the cumsum function. However, is there a way to remove rows with duplicate jobs and keep the last Percent_Completion associated with the job? Perhaps taking only the unique jobs that have a max Percent_Completion might work?